# SQL Server 2008 replicating to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2008, msde2000

Has anyone implemented replication between SQL Server 2008 and MSDE2000? Does the merge replication work between these two databases?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 can both participate in replication topologies with SQL Server 2008. For SQL Server 2000 the minimum version is Service Pack 3 (SP3).

Ref: [Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx)

> When you replicate between or among
>   different versions of SQL Server, you
>   are usually limited to the
>   functionality of the earliest version
>   used. For example, if you upgrade a
>   Distributor to an instance of SQL
>   Server 2008, but you have a Publisher
>   that is running an instance of SQL
>   Server 2005 and a Subscriber that is
>   running an instance of SQL Server
>   2000, you are limited to the general
>   functionality and replication
>   functionality of SQL Server 2000.

There are some breaking changes in the security model detailed here: [Breaking Changes in SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143470.aspx)